# fetch matching from and to date in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have following data set in the database,

`name    city        from       to
john    ny   01.03.2005   09.06.2005
john    ln   10.06.2005   29.09.2005
john    ca   30.09.2005   20.09.2013
arun    va   20.09.2007   15.09.2008
arun    ny   16.09.2008   09.06.2009`

and when I search for given input as name: john and from as 10.05.2005 and to as 02.09.2005 which should return first two records and if I provide 04.06.2005 and 09.06.2005 then it should return first record.

I have this query `(('input from date' <= 'db from date' and 'db from date' < 'input to date') or ('db from date' <= 'input from date' and 'input from date' < 'db to date'))` but the dataset I search is huge and this query keeps running. I'm trying to look for an effecient query.

Hope someone can provide answer here. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Doesn't this help  you. `WHERE name = 'john' and (FROM_DATE >= TO_DATE('10.05.2005','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE <= TO_DATE('02.09.2005','DD.MM.YYYY'))` Index on name,from_date should favour you. FROM_DATE should always be lesser than to_date. So you need not validate.

Comment: isn't that skips the first record?

Comment: but my requirement is that if the given input falls with the from and to then it should return that record.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique date values in [from] and [to] columns, you can set unique clustered (or non-clustered) indexes to these columns (ascending). if it doesn't help, pls comment again

Comment: Thought of having index but this table is mutated often and I can't set the index.

Comment: There's one more way to work easily with date values: Just convert date values to Decimal Data Types. For example, convert 31.01.2014 14:32:06 to 20140131 and 143206. Then paste 20140131 FROMDATE also have to convert your filters to Decimal Type. It's because SQL queries work on Decimal type faster than Date Type (sorry for my bad English)